# Howto grab console output made by $this->info() in phpunit code

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing phpunit code for some console command (in laravel 9.x).
The command will generate a report like:

```
    2023-05-08 16:14:30
    Some Awsome Batch
    
    Batch Status : SUCCESS
    Start Time : 2023-05-08 16:14:26
    End Time : 2023-05-08 16:14:27
    DryRun: yes
    Billing month:
```

In real env, the above text is displayed in green color,
because it was produced by `$this->info()`, and `$this` is derived from `Illuminate\Console\Command`.

Now I am working on  phpunit to verify that report, like following:

```php
    public function testBadBillingMonth()
    {

        $cmd = $this->artisan('command:GasLimitedTimePointGrant', [
            '--billingMonth' => '20230a'
        ]); 
        $cmd->run();

        printf("\n=====\n%s\n", $cmd->test->getActualOutput() ); // I got blank here :(

    }
```

My trouble is that, the 'output' catched by phpunit is 'blank', my little green report is gone.

If I use `printf` instead of `$this->info()` to produce the report,
I woule be able to grab the content of report by $cmd->test->getActualOutput(),
but I  can't modify my test target  to fit my test code.
And we also use `$this->error()`, `$this->warn()` respectively.

So can we grab the output made by `$this->error()`, `$this->warn()`, `$this->info()` in phpunit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828985/how-to-inspect-the-actual-laravel-command-output-while-writing-tests helps.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, that is it!  I got saved :) Thanks a lot.